# Is SignedObject safe to deliver to client applications

Tags: java, encryption

```
SignedObject  (Serializable  object, PrivateKey  signingKey, Signature  signingEngine)
```

Is it safe to serialize and deliver this object to a client application?  Is there a way that they might get hold of the PrivateKey through reflection?

I want to use this object to hold a digital signature as well as the data that was signed.

Comment: This sort of thing can go wrong in surprising ways. For instance, side-channel attacks. I would certainly be more comfortable not doing this sort of thing.

Comment: You're not comfortable with digital signatures? That's all this is. There are no side-channel attacks because the private key is not available to the client application.

Comment: good find, I didn't realize this class even existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialized objects include only the object itself and the signature (and the algorithm used for signing purposes), as noted here:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.security.SignedObject

As a result, it is safe to pass these around. Not only can the private key not be determined through that object alone, but it also cannot be tampered along the way, so the object will remain trusted (so long as the client verifies it).

Answer (score 0):

you can finde more info about java security here:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html